# Can I use .getClass() == .class or .getClass() == .class.getClass()?

Tags: java, class, equals

I'm testing if an `Object` is equals than a specific `class` type.
For example:

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        Object sourceObject = e.getSource();

        if (sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class.getClass()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            JComboBox<String> jComboBox = (JComboBox<String>) sourceObject;
```

So, what comparison method should I use? `sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class.getClass()` or `sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class`?

Or simply use `instanceof` to compare if can I cast safety the e.getSource() to JComboBox?

Comment: Check this for understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465253/comparing-two-classes-by-its-types-or-class-names

Comment: Use `instanceof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case 1 :-
if (sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class) is correct way of comparsion as getClass() will return runtime class of sourceObject object and JComboBox.class will return class too

case 2:-
sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class.getClass() it will throw incompatible op-rend type Exception

Comment: Thanks. For the example I posted. Do you think is better use your answer or the instanceof reserved word. I just want to compare the two types for casting purposes.

Comment: In case of casting, it is better to go with instanceof operator instead of comparison

Comment: Why do you believe `sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class.getClass()` will throw exception? That is perfectly *valid* code, though it will always be `false`, so it is *incorrect* code, but still *valid* code. No exception thrown. `JComboBox.class` is a `Class` object for the `JComboBox` class. `JComboBox.class.getClass()` is a `Class` object for the `Class` class itself.

Comment: Please try to run this code on compiler, it will  throw incompatible type exception as sourceObject.getClass()  will return runtime class of sourceObject object  and JComboBox.class.getClass() will return Class of Class class itself.hence there is no relation between these two, it should of similar type or parent- child relation otherwise it will throw compatible type exception

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: `sourceObject.getClass() == JComboBox.class` is correct.

The result of `someObj.getClass()` is the `Class` object that represents the class of someObj.
And `SomeClass.class` is also the corresponding object that represents the class `SomeClass`.
So `SomeClass.class.getClass()` returns the `Class` object that represents the class of the object `SomeClass.class`

This code outputs `true`

```
Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(d.getClass() == Date.class);
```

While this gives a compilation error.

```
Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(d.getClass() == Date.class.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks. For the example I posted. Do you think is better use your answer or the instanceof reserved word. I just want to compare the two types for casting purposes.

Comment: `obj instanceof Clazz` only works when the class of obj is a supertype or subtype of Clazz, or else it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is whether the cast to `JComboBox` will work, then use:

```
if (sourceObject instanceof JComboBox) {
```

That way, any potential subclass of `JComboBox` will also be handled by your code, which is likely what should happen, since a subclass of `JComboBox` *is a* `JComboBox`.