# How to cast type safety a Object to JComboBox<String>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        Object sourceObject = evt.getSource();

        if (sourceObject instanceof JComboBox<?>) {
            JComboBox<String> jComboBox = (JComboBox<String>) sourceObject;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best and correct casting for generics type safety and avoiding suppress the warning?

Comment: This looks so [*familiar*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538976/can-i-use-getclass-class-or-getclass-class-getclass/59539049#59539049).

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm new with Java. Trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You nailed it. Runtime `instanceof` checks don't check generic parameters so the way you have shown it is the standard way that it is done.

Comment: I think should use the SupressWarnings Unchecked then. Thanks.